# How to query three different tables to find out specific information

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Ok, this is a triple table query, and I am very very confused in how to go about this, let along construct it.

I'm trying to find all the tutoring session tied to a specific email address.

The tables information is listed down beneath.

User, TutorSession, & SessionUser.

TutorSession belongs to User

Users has many SessionUser

Here are the attributes of each table:

**User**

```
                     :id => :integer,
                  :email => :string,
     :encrypted_password => :string,
   :reset_password_token => :string,
 :reset_password_sent_at => :datetime,
    :remember_created_at => :datetime,
          :sign_in_count => :integer,
     :current_sign_in_at => :datetime,
        :last_sign_in_at => :datetime,
     :current_sign_in_ip => :string,
        :last_sign_in_ip => :string,
             :created_at => :datetime,
             :updated_at => :datetime,
             :first_name => :string,
              :last_name => :string,
               :provider => :string,
                    :uid => :string,
             :roles_mask => :integer,
       :last_activity_at => :datetime,
              :time_zone => :string,
               :imported => :boolean,
   :authentication_token => :string,
:getting_started_dismissed => :boolean,
         :schedule_valid => :datetime

 add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
 add_index "users", ["first_name"], :name => "index_users_on_first_name"
 add_index "users", ["last_name"], :name => "index_users_on_last_name"
 add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true
```

**TutorSession**

```
                  :id => :integer,
        :session_code => :string,
                :name => :string,
        :moderator_pw => :string,
         :attendee_pw => :string,
        :session_type => :string,
              :status => :string,
          :started_at => :datetime,
            :ended_at => :datetime,
   :tutor_pickup_type => :string,
       :recording_url => :string,
          :created_at => :datetime,
          :updated_at => :datetime,
        :requested_by => :integer,
   :subject_full_name => :string,
   :student_dismissed => :boolean,
           :school_id => :integer,
 :tutoring_subject_id => :integer,
:tutor_appointment_id => :integer,
  :white_board_status => :string,
      :session_length => :integer
```

**SessionUser**

```
  t.integer  "tutor_session_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "usertype"
  t.string   "url"
  t.datetime "login_at"
  t.string   "logout_at"
  t.string   "flag"
  t.datetime "created_at",        :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",        :null => false
  t.string   "user_agent_string"
  t.string   "browser"
  t.string   "os"
end

add_index "session_users", ["tutor_session_id"], :name =>    "index_session_users_on_session_id"
add_index "session_users", ["user_id"], :name => "index_session_users_on_user_id"
```

**EDIT**

I made a mistaking in stating how the tables were related to each other. Sorry, my head is somewhere else.

**SessionUser** belongs to both **user** and **tutor_session**

**TutorSession** has many **session_users**

**User** has many **session_users**

Comment: Isn't this a simple n:m (many-to-many) relationship? Surely the Rails documentation covers that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this query:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM   users         u
JOIN   session_user su ON u.id = su.user_id
JOIN   tutor_session s ON s.id = su.tutor_session_id
WHERE  u.email = 'foo@bar'
```

Comment: I ran your answer literally, and got this `SyntaxError: unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
...er su ON u.id = su.user_id JOIN tutor_session s ON s.id = su...`
...                               ^

Comment: @user2730725: You need to use your *actual* table names.

Comment: all right, I'll admit it, I'm confused by your query. What does 's' stand for? Because you use 'su' which I know you mean session_user. But confused by 's.' By the way, I made an edit to my post.

Comment: `tutor_session s` is short for `tutor_session AS s`. `s` is a **[table alias](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)**. As to your edit: I anticipated this mistake already. It's a classical n:m situation.

Comment: this is the query that I'm running `Select tutor_session from users u join session_user su on u.id = su.user_id join tutor_session s on s.id = su.tutor_session_id where u.email = 'blah@fake.net'`]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your model looks like, but should be as easy as:

```
User.find_by_email('someone@example.com').tutor_sessions
```

For this to work your models should look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions, :class_name => SessionUser
  has_many :tutor_sessions, :through => :sessions
end
```

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in explaining how the tables were linked. I've made an edit since then. Does that help?

Comment: @user2730725 did you try adding `has_many :tutor_sessions, :through => :session_users` to your model?